# Getting latest version of unreleased app on Boss phone

Tags: ios

Hi so I need to know the most efficient and quickest way to get an unreleased iPhone app onto my boss's phone.  It is not up on test flight, it is just a local application.  He is not in the office and I need him to have the latest version on his phone.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

1. If you can, just upload it to Test flight
2. Use a 3rd party system for this (hockey app, fabric, etc.)
3. Ad-hoc deployment - You can sign and distribute it yourself, but it's really not worth the effort when there are so many available solutions.
4. Plug the phone in (but obviously not if he is OOO)

If for whatever reason you cannot use test flight, I'd go for fabric. You'll need to get him to signup and then setup your provisioning profile with his device identifier, and upload the build.

Comment: 5. Use plain old Ad-hoc deployment.

Comment: Ad-hoc deployment, that's what they call it! Added as part of #3.